# CheckList Box inside a gridview shows alert only when if it is not postback as the function is called on rowbound of grid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, checklistbox

I have `CheckListBox` inside a `GridView`. I need an alert when the checkbox gets clicked. It is currently done on the `Gridview.RowDataBound()` event, so it happens only one time in if it is not postback. How do I make the alert to work every time when the page loads.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code how you're wiring up the click event inside Gridview Rowdatabound?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery like below:

```
<head>
<title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
                alert(this.checked);

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're doing something like this in your `RowDataBound` event.

```
   protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var cbListSource = getDataSource(); // get the data source values for the checkboxlist to bind to
            CheckBoxList cblItems = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("cblItems");
            cblItems.DataSource = cbListSource;
            cblItems.DataTextField = "QuestionName";
            cblItems.DataValueField = "QuestionId";
            cblItems.DataBind();

            cblItems.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Your alert text goes in here')");
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can use javascript or jquery to achieve the same result.